# Observable is returning the data later

Tags: angular, http, promise, rxjs, observable

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getTypeList();
   this.buildTemplate();
}

private getTypeList(): void {
        this.searchService.getViewTypeList(this.org)
            .subscribe(viewTypeList => {
                this.viewTypeList = viewTypeList;
            });
      }

this.buildTemplate() : void {
  console.log(this.viewTypeList);
  ****** some code work on viewTypeList***
}
```

The problem is that `console.log(this.viewTypeList);`  shows  undefined in the method..
I know this is asynch call and takes time to complete , but in the mean time my next code of  `this.getTypeList()` gets executed and shows undefined .

**i want that my all remaining processing should be done once the data is avaialble from http service. someThing like me code should not proceed without the data from service as it gives undefined for all rest methods in code. Or is there any way to do that i can avail the data from service beforehand to process that**

Comment: Have `getTypedList` return the observable instead of subscribing to it.

Comment: Don't try to mix conventional function style with reactive paradigm. This is the root cause of most rxjs issues .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http calls are async calls. Subsequent call will get executed and will not wait for the promise to be resolve.

Your dependent code should be written once it resolved.

Instead of calling `buildTemplate()` in ngOnInit call it once API call resolved.

```
private getTypeList(): void {
    this.searchService.getViewTypeList(this.org)
        .subscribe(viewTypeList => {
            this.viewTypeList = viewTypeList;
            this.buildTemplate();  //here your data is available.
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **this.buildTemplate()** from **ngOnInit** and put inside the subscribe.

```
private getTypeList(): void {
        this.searchService.getViewTypeList(this.org)
            .subscribe(viewTypeList => {
                this.viewTypeList = viewTypeList;
                this.buildTemplate();
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `this.buildTemplate()` within the `subscribe()` method instead of calling in ngoninit.

This way template will be built only when data is loaded from server. In the meanwhile you can show dummy info like loading status.

Answer (score 1):

You should firstly check how observable and promise works and difference between async and sync processes.

If we look at  your situation. You use observable async process. What does it mean? It means your codes work independent. next line doesn't wait if async function finish or not. So If you want to call this function after async finish then you have two way firstone is take second function inside async function's subscribe method.

```
.subscribe(viewTypeList => {
            this.viewTypeList = viewTypeList;
            this.buildTemplate(); 
        });
```

another way is using `promise` with `await`  rather than `observable`. Then it will work like sync. It will wait for finish first function.